# Kaa docker deployment

Tags: kaa

I'm trying to install Kaa using Docker. I follow the installation guide (https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Docker-deployment/#deployment-process) step by step:

1- install docker

2- install docker compose

3- build kaa project locally

4- Run the following command from the server/containers/docker directory.

docker build --build-arg setupfile=kaa-node.deb -t kaa-node:0.10.1 .

Then Single node installation

1- Specifying the TRANSPORT_PUBLIC_INTERFACE parameter in the server/containers/docker/docker-compose-1-node/kaa-example.env file.

ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF; exit}'

2- cd docker-compose-1-node/mariadb-mongodb/

At this point everything was going OK. But when I run the next command (3-) I get an error message at the end as shown in the image:

3-  docker-compose up

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKYuv.png)

Any help please. I need to solve this problem !!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are referring to image tag **0.10.1** but actually have/need **0.10.0**
If you haven't solved this one by now, it is possible that the documentation is **NOT** 100% correct.